# How to remove ItemField from the ItemFields using C#

Tags: 2011, tom.net

I have an ItemFields object which has got all the ItemFields of a Component.

I want to remove a particular ItemField from it and return the entire ItemFields collection, so the code should be as below:

```
public static void WriteAllNodes(this XmlWriter Xml, ItemFields itemFields, String ignoreFieldNames)
{
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ignoreFieldNames))
  {
    String[] strSplitFields = ignoreFieldNames.Split(',');
    foreach (String fieldName in strSplitFields)
    {
      if (itemFields != null && itemFields.Contains(fieldName))
      {
        itemFields = itemFields.RemoveItemField(fieldName); 
        //What could be the best logic for this RemoveItemField function?
      }         
    }
  }
}
```

But the API does not contain a method `ItemFields.RemoveItemField()`, what can I use to remove an ItemField from the ItemFields?

Comment: Have you tried removing the _value_ of the itemfield?

Comment: I think setting the value of field to string.empty will remove the field.    TextField field = strSplitFields["YourFieldName"] as TextField;
                field.Value = string.empty;

Comment: I am not getting any option of removing value of ItemField?

Comment: @Alok but in this case I have to loop it for all the types and then do the above stuff

Comment: You need to first cast the ItemField to the appropriate Field type - SingleLineTextField, or XhtmlField, etc - then you can call field.Values.Clear() or something along those lines.

Comment: @Manoj:- That is right. You have to loop all fields and set your required field with empty and then save your component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there indeed isn't a direct method to remove an `ItemField` from a `ItemFields` collection, so you have to use the XML in the `ItemFields` collection (you can use the `component.Content` directly also of course):

```cs
// get itemfields collection from Component
ItemFields itemFields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);
XmlElement content = itemFields.ToXml();

// remove field from itemsfields collection directly in XML
XmlNode nodeToRemove = content.SelectSingleNode("//path.to.node");
content.RemoveChild(nodeToRemove);

// sync changed content back to Component before saving
component.Content = content;
component.Save();
```

Please make sure you sync back the changed `ItemFields` collection to the Component before saving because this is a detached collection. Any changes you make in the `ItemFields` collection will have no direct effect on the Component (or item) it comes from.

## update

If you don't want to update the Component, and just need an updated ItemFields collection, then create that as follows:

```cs
// your current itemFields variable as input
XmlElement content = itemFields.ToXml();

// remove field from itemsfields collection directly in XML
XmlNode nodeToRemove = content.SelectSingleNode("//path.to.node");
content.RemoveChild(nodeToRemove);

// update itemfields collection 
itemFields = new ItemFields(content, component.Schema);
```

## update 2

As per @Nuno's comment, you can also keep using the ItemFields collection and clear all the values of a certain itemField in there:

```cs
((TextField)itemFields[fieldName]).Values.Clear();
```

Comment: I don't want to save the component, I just need the updated ItemFields, which I will pass to my function to render the desired output

Comment: you should just create an xml document and remove the desired node from that.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution is to use the XML directly and not the TOM.NET API.

All content in Tridion is stored as XML underneath and the APIs in both TOM.NET and the Core Service expose this XML.  Using TOM.NET you would use something like GetXML and then you can manipulate the XML to your needs, and as long as it validates against the Tridion Schema you're good to go.

Otherwise, if you're not in a template or event system I would suggest using the Core service and remove the undesired field from the XML and call the Update method of the Core Service client and send back the modified XML.